# Factorize this polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ into factors of the first exponent in the cases when D>0, D=0

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

The previous request was to prove the identity $ax^2+bx+c=a[(x+(b/2a)^2-(D/4a^2)]$, where $D=b^2-4ac$
And I proved it from the left to the right, which means I managed to express $ax^2+bx+c$ as $a[(x+(b/2a)^2-(D/4a^2)]$.
 What should I do next?

Comment: If you've already proven both sides of the equation equal, what more do you want?

Comment: $a^2-b = (a+\sqrt b)(a-\sqrt b)$

Comment: I want to explain me what happens in the cases when D>0 and D=0, I know that when D>0, it is factorized the same way and when D=0, we eleminate the part (D/4a^2, but how can we express it matematically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your original goal is to factorise, using $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$,
$$\begin{align*}
ax^2+bx+c &= a\left[\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2 - \frac D{4a^2}\right]\\
&= a\left[\left(x+\frac b{2a}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\sqrt D}{2a}\right)^2\right]\\
&= a\left(x+\frac b{2a}+\frac{\sqrt D}{2a}\right)\left(x+\frac b{2a}-\frac{\sqrt D}{2a}\right)\\
&= a\left(x-\frac {-b-\sqrt D}{2a}\right)\left(x-\frac {-b+\sqrt D}{2a}\right)\\
\end{align*}$$
This is a more general case where $D\ge 0$. If $D=0$, then the two factors are the same, i.e. have a second power:
$$ax^2+bx+c = a\left(x-\frac {-b}{2a}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

If $D = 0$, then you have $$ax^2 + bx + c = a\left(x + \frac b{2a}\right)^2$$ where $c = \left(\dfrac b{2a}\right)^2 = \dfrac{b^2}{4a^2}$.

If $D> 0$, then you have the identity you've proven. $$ax^2+bx+c=a[(x+(b/2a)^2-(D/4a^2)] = a\left(x-\frac {-b-\sqrt D}{2a}\right)\left(x-\frac {-b+\sqrt D}{2a}\right)$$

The right side follows because you have a difference of squares of the form $x^2 -y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$.